How to Load Data from Apache Iceberg to AWS Neptune Using Apache Spark Without AWS Services? Is It Scalable?
I am currently working on a project where I need to load data from an Apache Iceberg table into an AWS Neptune graph database. I want to perform this task using an Apache Spark, but I prefer not to use any additional AWS services such as AWS DMS for this integration. The volume of data that I am talking about is 400GB initially after that every day around 15GB incremental data. I'll be loading multiple tables  which has the data of vertices and edges.
Here's a brief overview of my setup and requirements:

Data Source: Apache Iceberg table
Target Database: AWS Neptune
Intermediate Processing: Apache Spark

My Current Approach
I have written a Spark program in Scala that reads data from the Iceberg table and uses the Gremlin API to insert the data into Neptune. Here is the simplified version of the code:
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Row, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.iceberg.spark.Spark3Util
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.{Client, Cluster}
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteGraph
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.{AwsBasicCredentials, StaticCredentialsProvider}
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptune.NeptuneClient

object NeptuneSparkApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Initialize Spark session
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("NeptuneSparkApp")
      .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.uri", "thrift://localhost:9083") // Update with your Hive Metastore URI
      .getOrCreate()

    // Define AWS Neptune endpoint and credentials
    val neptuneEndpoint = "your-neptune-endpoint:8182"
    val neptuneRegion = "your-region"
    val awsAccessKeyId = "your-access-key-id"
    val awsSecretAccessKey = "your-secret-access-key"

    // Initialize Neptune Client
    val credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey)
    val neptuneClient = NeptuneClient.builder()
      .region(Region.of(neptuneRegion))
      .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
      .build()

    // Connect to Neptune
    val cluster = Cluster.build(neptuneEndpoint).create()
    val client = cluster.connect()
    val graph = RemoteGraph.open(client, "g")

    // Read data from Iceberg table
    val icebergTable: DataFrame = spark.read
      .format("iceberg")
      .load("spark_catalog.db.table_name") // Update with your Iceberg table path

    // Function to insert data into Neptune
    def insertDataToNeptune(row: Row): Unit = {
      val g = graph.traversal()
      g.addV("person")
        .property("id", row.getAs[String]("id"))
        .property("name", row.getAs[String]("name"))
        .property("age", row.getAs[Int]("age"))
        .next()
    }

    // Apply the function to each row in the DataFrame
    icebergTable.collect().foreach(insertDataToNeptune)

    // Close the connection
    client.close()
    cluster.close()

    // Stop the Spark session
    spark.stop()
  }
}


This is absolutely possible, as we have created a means to do this in AWS Glue (basically built in on Spark).
We have some examples written for this, though they were written with PySpark and Glue in mind: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-python-utils#using-neptune-python-utils-with-aws-glue
The approach should be similar though.  There are really two main things that you need to consider:

Batch multiple nodes/edges/properties into queries that insert ~200 "object" (an object being an empty node/edge or a property; a node with 4 properties is 5 "objects") into a single write query.
Use concurrency:  Each Neptune instance has 2 query execution threads per vCPU.  Your Spark loader should use a concurrency to match the concurrency available on the Neptune writer instance.
Use a bigger writer instance to drive more throughput - more concurrency equals higher writer throughput.  You can always scale-down the writer instance after your initial load has completed.
Account for possible contention with concurrent writes (deadlocks).  If you insert nodes and edges separately, you should mostly avoid these.  But just make sure your code has retries and error handling included to avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions (CMEs - which equate to deadlocks).

